# Stop receiving real time updates for a Facebook page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, real-time, facebook-php-sdk

I have followed the instructions on this page:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#realtime

But I can't get the **Deleting an App** section to work.
This is the case with both the PHP SDK and with Facebook's Graph API Explorer.

First I add an app to get real time updates by POSTing to

```
/<page_id>/tabs
```

with the **app_id** parameter set to my App ID. I also pass an Access Token for the page.

This returns 'true' in the Graph Explorer, and '1' with the PHP SDK, which I understand means success in both cases. I know this is true as I have received data to my real time endpoint.

However, I also need to be able to delete these subscriptions, per page.
The documentation suggests this is done by performing a DELETE to

```
/<page_id>/tabs/app_<app_id>
```

Again passing the same Access Token as before.
In both the Graph Explorer and the PHP SDK, this returns:

```
(#100) Tab is not installed or not removable: <The same app_id I passed>
```

I've seen a couple of other people reporting the same issue, but apparently no solutions. If anyone has managed to figure this out, I would hugely appreciate your thoughts.

Comment: Can you just go to app settings and remove it there?

Comment: There doesn't appear to be an option for this.

Comment: When you go to https://developers.facebook.com/apps/PUT_YOUR_APP_ID_HERE/realtime?ref=nav theres no subscription?

Comment: Yes there's the options for the subscription, but i'm trying to manage the link between that and the pages that have added the app and are sending events to us.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. I am unable to stop Facebook real-time updates as it is described in the docs. Seems like a bug.

Comment: Yes I believe it must be. Closest I've found on Facebook's site is https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/503381706394259

Comment: I've don the same steps and get the same results, both with the PHP SDK and the Explorer.

Comment: The above bug report was assigned "high" priority on nov 20th. How many days until they fix it ?

Comment: Not sure but let's hope it isn't much longer!

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible alternatives:

Go to `https://www.facebook.com/{page_id}/settings?tab=apps` and manually remove the application from the page. If the app is not there, it has already been removed.

Or:

You can use the [Real-time Update documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/app/subscriptions/) and use a DELETE API call to unsubscribe the page from real-time updates. However, if your application is used with more than once page, it will also unsubscribe the other pages.

Comment: As mentioned in my initial post, the DELETE API call doesn't work. Facebook have acknowledged this issue here https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/503381706394259

Comment: Does the other method work? I.e. deleting the tab from the Page Settings?

Comment: This may give idea of a complete flow of page subscription: http://tech-brains.blogspot.in/2015/04/real-time-updates-for-facebook-page.html